# No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignParentCenter' in package 'android'

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imagebutton

I'm getting two errors when attempting to add a scrollable navigation bar to the bottom of my screen. I've never seen this error before and the answers I've found thus far do not seem to resolve the issue I'm having.

### ERRORS:

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignParentCenter' in package 'android'   home.xml    /idg/res/layout line 298    Android AAPT Problem
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignParentCenter' in package 'android'   home.xml    /idg/res/layout line 361    Android AAPT Problem
```

Any input is greatly appreciated.

### XML SOURCE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- The rest of your layout (TextView, ScrollView, etc) -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/groupScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Throw &apos;Em Up"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn1"
                    android:layout_width="27dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="by DJ Generic  |"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="  100,000 views"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp" >
            </View>

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/youtubethumbnailview1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Bulls On Parade"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn"
                    android:layout_width="27dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="by Rage Against The Machine  |"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="  100,000 views"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp" >
            </View>

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/youtubethumbnailview2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Isaac Daniel on CNN with Anderson Cooper"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn"
                    android:layout_width="27dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="by idconex  |"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2a"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="  100,000 views"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp" >
            </View>

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/youtubethumbnailview3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Bulls On Parade"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn"
                    android:layout_width="27dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="by Rage Against The Machine  |"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="  100,000 views"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp" >
            </View>

            <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/youtubethumbnailview4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentCenter="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@drawable/selstation_up_btn" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Isaac Daniel on CNN with Anderson Cooper"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn"
                    android:layout_width="27dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1a"
                    android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="by idconex  |"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightgrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="  100,000 views"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#AAFFFFFF" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/scroll_lt_arrow" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentCenter="true"
                    android:text="@drawable/selstation_up_btn" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/scroll_rt_arrow" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="5dp" >
            </View>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Is that your entire xml file? it seems you're missing the namespace declaration along with the starting xml tag.

Comment: Updated it (apologies - it appears to have been cutoff)

Comment: That takes care of the namespace but I still don't see the xml tag <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>. Just trying to cover all options

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such layout attribute in `LinearLayout` nor `RelativeLayout`.

- For `LinearLayout`, you need to use [`android:gravity="center"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_gravity).
- For `RelativeLayout`, you need to set [`android:layout_centerInParent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_centerInParent) to true.

For the linear layout, you need to make sure your view is assigned enough room (via its `layout_width/height` and/or via `layout_gravity`) so that it makes sense to render its contents centered. For RelativeLayout, the container must be large enough so that it makes sense to center the view inside it.